# What does $\ker(A) \cap \operatorname{im}(A)$ say about the rank and nullity of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I'm trying to investigate what $\ker(A) \cap \operatorname{im}(A)$ implies for $\operatorname{rank}(A)$ and $\operatorname{null}(A)$. Specifically, if we have some vector, say
$$ 
\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}
\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}
\newcommand{\null}{\operatorname{null}}
v = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    3 \\
    4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
in $\ker(A) \cap \im(A)$, what does that imply about $\rank(A)$ and $\null(A)$?

Here is some work I've done so far:

- $A$ must be a $n \times 4$ matrix. That means $A$ has four columns, and so $\dim(A) = 4$, and so $\rank(A) + \null(A) = 4$ by the Rank-Nullity Theorem.
- Clearly, $\rank(A)$ cannot be $0$, because $\rank(A) = \dim(\im(A)) > 0$, since we know the given vector $v$ is in $\im(A)$ (which means $\im(A)$ cannot have dimension $0$). This implies $\null(A)$ cannot be $4$. Likewise, $\null(A)$ cannot be $0$ because $v \in \ker(A)$.
- In fact, $A$ must be a $4 \times 4$ matrix. This is because $v \in \ker(A)$ implies $Av$ is a valid matrix product (so $v$ has the same number of rows as $A$'s columns; that is, $4$), and because $v \in \im(A)$ implies that the product $Aw$ for some vector $w$ has length $4$, which implies $A$ has $4$ rows as well.

However, I haven't been able to find examples of (or prove the impossibility of) when $\rank(A) = 1, 2, 3$. Could anyone finish this problem?

Comment: @TedShifrin Could you explain how these are "subspaces of different **subspaces**"? I know that if the linear map $A$ is from $V$ to $W$, then ker$(A)$ and im$(A)$ are subspaces of $V$ and $W$, respectively. But $V$ and $W$ are just regular vector spaces, not subspaces, right?

Comment: The transformations $T(x,y,z,w) =(y,z,w,0)$, $U(x,y,z,w)=(z,w,0,0)$, and $R(x,y,z,w)=(w,0,0,0)$ have ranks 3, 2, and 1, respectively. The image of all of them intersect their nullspace nontrivially. For $T$, the nullspace is contained in the range. For $U$, the nullspace equals the range. For $R$, the range is contained in the nullspace.

Comment: (A suitable change of basis matrix can be used to make sure any specific vector you want lies in the intersection).

Comment: I had deleted my comment because I realized the OP had addressed this. But the delete did not take. My apologies. There was also a silly typo in it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry, how does your definition of $T$ cause $[1, 2, 3, 4]$ to be in ker$(A)$? Shouldn't it have to map to the $0$-vector?

Comment: It doesn't, but just compose with an appropriate invertible transformation and you can get any vector you pre-specify to be in the kernel.

Comment: Because you can make invertible  linear transformations that send any four linearly independent vectors to the standard basis (or to any four linearly independent vectors) the precise values of the vectors don't matter, just the dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B$ be the following matrux:
$$B=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right).$$
Note that the nullspace is spanned by $(1,0,0,0)$ (transpose where appropriate) and the range by $(1,0,0,0)$, $(0,1,0,0)$, and $(0,0,1,0)$. So the nullspace is contained in the range, and $B$ has rank $3$.

Now, "my" intersection is spanned by $(1,0,0,0)$, and you want it to have $(1,2,3,4)$ instead. So let $C$ be given by
$$C=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&0\\
2&1&0&0\\
3&0&1&0\\
4&0&0&1
\end{array}\right), \quad\text{so }C^{-1}=
\left(\begin{array}{rccc}
1&0&0&0\\
-2&1&0&0\\
-3&0&1&0\\
-4&0&0&1
\end{array}\right).$$

Now let $A=CBC^{-1}$. Since $C^{-1}$ sends $(1,2,3,4)$ to $(1,0,0,0)$, and $B$ maps it to $(0,0,0,0)$, we have that $(1,2,3,4)$ lies in the nullspace of $A$. On the other hand, an easy calculation shows that $A$ sends $(0,1,0,0)$ to $(1,2,3,4)$, so $(1,2,3,4)$ lies in the intersection of the nullspace and ranges of $A$.

Taking $A^2$ you get a matrix with rank 2 whose range equals the nullspace. Here $(1,2,3,4)$ is the image of $(0,0,1,0)$. Finally taking $A^3$ you get. matrix of rank 1 whose range is contained in the nullspace, and here the image of $(0,0,0,1)$ is $(1,2,3,4)$.

You can get any particular vector on the intersection doing something similar. So the only thing you can deduce from the intersection being nontrivial is that the matrix has rank less than $4$ and more than $0$. Similar statements hold for any dimension: you just get that the matrix is nonzero and not of full rank. All other ranks are possible.

Even more generally, for any $n$ and any $k$, $1\leq k\leq \frac{n}{2}$, given any $k$ linearly independent vectors $v_1,\ldots v_k$, you can find an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with $v_1,\ldots,v_k\in N(A)\cap R(A)$, and $k\leq\mathrm{rank}(A)\leq n-k$.